# I cant retrieve footprints from place information

Tags: osmnx

`enter code here`When I try to retrieve footprints from place name using

```py
import osmx as ox
tags = {'building': True}
gdf = ox.geometries_from_place('Piedmont, California, USA', tags)
```

I get the following error message:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Argument must be Polygonal or LinearRing

PredicateError: Failed to evaluate <_FuncPtr object at 0x13a2ea120>
```

In the past, I have successfully used the old version to retrieve footprints `ox.footprints_from_place()`. However this does not work anymore, and neither does the new method. Does anybody had the same issues with the new version (1.0.1) of the osmnx package?

Due to stackoverflow restrictions I can't post the complete traceback message. It seems that osmnx does not create the required polygon. The first error entries are:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PredicateError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-98877af3189c> in <module>
      1 import osmnx as ox
      2 tags = {'building': True}
----> 3 gdf = ox.geometries_from_place('Piedmont, California, USA', tags)

/opt/anaconda3/envs/gerdaenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osmnx/geometries.py in geometries_from_place(query, tags, which_result, buffer_dist)
    214 
    215     # create GeoDataFrame using this polygon(s) geometry
--> 216     gdf = geometries_from_polygon(polygon, tags)
    217 
    218     return gdf

/opt/anaconda3/envs/gerdaenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osmnx/geometries.py in geometries_from_polygon(polygon, tags)
    264 
    265     # create GeoDataFrame from the downloaded data
--> 266     gdf = _create_gdf(response_jsons, polygon, tags)
    267 
    268     return gdf

/opt/anaconda3/envs/gerdaenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osmnx/geometries.py in _create_gdf(response_jsons, polygon, tags)
    428 
    429         # Apply .buffer(0) to any invalid geometries
--> 430         gdf = _buffer_invalid_geometries(gdf)
    431 
    432         # Filter final gdf to requested tags and query polygon

/opt/anaconda3/envs/gerdaenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osmnx/geometries.py in _buffer_invalid_geometries(gdf)
    891 
    892         # create a filter for rows with invalid geometries
--> 893         invalid_geometry_filter = ~gdf["geometry"].is_valid
    894 
    895         # if there are invalid geometries

/opt/anaconda3/envs/gerdaenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/base.py in is_valid(self)
    168         """Returns a ``Series`` of ``dtype('bool')`` with value ``True`` for
    169         geometries that are valid."""
--> 170         return _delegate_property("is_valid", self)
    171 
    172     @property
```

The last traceback messages are :

```
/opt/anaconda3/envs/gerdaenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/predicates.py in __call__(self, this)
     23     def __call__(self, this):
     24         self._validate(this)
---> 25         return self.fn(this._geom)

/opt/anaconda3/envs/gerdaenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/geos.py in errcheck_predicate(result, func, argtuple)
    582     """Result is 2 on exception, 1 on True, 0 on False"""
    583     if result == 2:
--> 584         raise PredicateError("Failed to evaluate %s" % repr(func))
    585     return result
    586 

PredicateError: Failed to evaluate <_FuncPtr object at 0x13a2ea120>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the complete traceback message and a complete, minimal, reproducible code snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @gboeing I added a longer version of the traceback message. Is this sufficient?

Comment: What versions of geopandas and shapely are you using in this environment? How did you install all the packages in the environment?

Comment: @gboeing the version of geopandas is 0.8.2 installed via conda

Comment: Without the other answers it's tough to guess what's going on here. Did you install OSMnx according to its installation [instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)? If so, try removing that env and recreating it again.

Comment: The used shapely version is 1.7.1. Since osmnx is one package of several packages I need I installed osmnx in a defined conda environment.